# Unable to format number with comma and dots

Tags: jquery

I want to numbers to separated with comma and dots but i can't.

I had tried toLocaleString to achieve my numbers in formatted order which i want but fail.

here is my code.

```
var totalsum = 0;
jQuery('td.column-total').each(function() {
//var value = jQuery(this).text();
//if(!isNaN(jQuery(this)) && jQuery(this).length!=0) {
totalsum += parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace('₦', '').replace(',', '').replace('.', ''));

//} 
//totalsum += parseFloat(string);
/*  if (!isNaN(value)) {
totalsum += value;
}*/
});
//Total = (parseFloat(subtotal)+parseFloat(tax)).toFixed(1);
console.log(totalsum);
jQuery("#totalexprenses").html(totalsum.toLocaleString("en-NGN") );
```

I want number in this format ₦25,300.00 but i am receiving number in this format 13,580,000

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the locale for `en`. If your number is in a string you will need to first transform it into a float. And if your number is a string with flipped separators you have to correct that format before.

**Example:**

```js
// Nummber as Float
let num_1_float = 1234567.89;
let num_1_formated = num_1_float.toLocaleString('en');
console.log(num_1_formated);

// Number as String
let num_2_string = '1234567.89';
let num_2_formated = parseFloat(num_2_string).toLocaleString('en');
console.log(num_2_formated);

// Number as String with flipped seperators
let num_3_string = '1.234.567,89';
let num_3_formated = parseFloat(num_3_string.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')).toLocaleString('en');
console.log(num_3_formated);
```

**Used inside a jQuery `each`-loop:**

```js
let totalsum = 0;
jQuery('td.column-total').each(function() {
  let text = jQuery(this).text(); // get text from cell
  let num = parseFloat(text.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')); // convert localized-string to parseable string for parseFloat.
  totalsum += num; // add to sum
});
console.log(totalsum);
jQuery("#totalexprenses").html(totalsum.toLocaleString("en"));
```

```css
#totalexprenses {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td class="column-total">12.000,11</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="column-total">23.350,00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="column-total">12.250,50</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="column-total">5500,02</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="column-total">8.255,75</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="totalexprenses">0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jan but you code is not working at my side i want I need formatted code inside each loop.

Comment: And i achieved desired result by using jquery.number  plugin

Comment: Converting strings and numbers, and nearly all pure javascript-code will work inside any jQuery each-loop. I extended my post with an example based on the code from your question. But to use some plugin for that is also an option.